# Checkable MenuItem appearing like ToggleButton in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create menu with `MenuItem` that is checkable, but looks like toggle button. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

You'd agree, this looks pretty ugly and it's not intuitive whether check mark belongs to `Views` or to `Actions`.

I'm aware that regular `CheckBox` has property `Appearance` which can be set to `Button`, making `CheckBox` appear like `ToggleButton`. However, there is no such property for `MenuItem` object.

I've also tried to add `ToggleButton` to menu, but it's appearance differs from what I'd expect. Here's the screenshot of this try:

[image]

I expect it to look something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to display toogle button control (or something appearing like it) in menu bar?

P.S. If You need my current test code, here it is:

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="True" x:Name="mnuMain">
    <MenuItem Header="File" x:Name="mnuFile">
        <MenuItem Header="Export List to Excel" x:Name="btnExportToExcel" Click="OnExportToExcel"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Views" x:Name="mnuViews">
        <MenuItem Header="Item1" x:Name="chkItem1" IsCheckable="true" Click="OnChkItem1Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Item2" x:Name="chkItem2" IsCheckable="true" Click="OnChkItem2Click" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Actions" x:Name="mnuActions" IsCheckable="true" >
        <!-- -->
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Analysis" x:Name="btnAnalysis" Click="OnAnalysisClick"/>
    <MenuItem Header="History" x:Name="btnHistory" Click="OnHistoryClick"/>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="tbTest" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="OnTbTestClick">Test</ToggleButton>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible to change MenuItem template for checkable and checked items, using custom style with triggers. Here is an example of a template (it was exctrcted from default MenuItem style)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF707070"/>

<Style x:Key="MenuItemToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Working like a charm, great answer. Thanks.